# Persistent volume with ReadWriteMany in GKE?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

Is there a way to make a volume as `ReadWriteMany` instead of having a NFS share?  Does GCP support `ReadWriteMany` volumes? I'm right now using NFS share and a persistent volume pointing it to NFS Share and then mounting it to pods. But this has a issue.

When NFS share has crashed or unable to connect, then all the pods that use this NFS persistent volume hangs. We can't even terminate the pods until the NFS issue is fixed. The pod doesn't crash either. We just had this issue and the pods were not responding for hours and terminating pod get stuck in `terminating` state. Once the NFS server issue is fixed then we can delete the pod and recreate it.

What can be done instead of having a NFS share?

Answer (score 3):

With Kubernetes, you need a NFS like persistent volume to ReadWriteMany. On Google Cloud, [Filestore](https://cloud.google.com/filestore) is the product to achieve that. You have [a documentation](https://cloud.google.com/filestore/docs/accessing-fileshares) that show you how to mount it to your pod

Comment: Is there a way to prevent pod from hanging when NFS share is unavailable?

Comment: Basically, the answer is "do everything you can to avoid ReadWriteMany, and use cloud-native services instead". The concepts of NFS don't really map well onto kubernetes, and you will save yourself a lot of trouble if you only use ReadWriteMany volumes after all else fails. For sharing files, using something like an object storage API (GCS or Amazon S3 or Openstack shift or MinIO or something along those lines) is a better idea in the long run.